# same trigger for different events

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table that keeps track of how many employees are assigned to a specific shift. Every time a user is assigned to a shift a trigger updates the table by increasing the `have` column by one. (this is due to performance issues)

the trigger fires after an insert. But i need it also to trigger when a user is deleted. I really didn't want to use 2 triggers that do basically the same.

Anyway to achieve this without using a procedure?

Comment: Use one procedure for different trigers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not achieve that is you don't want to use stored procedure and two triggers. In MySQL, trigger can be attached only to one **trigger_time** & **trigger_event** - since it is [defined](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) such way:

```
trigger_time: { BEFORE | AFTER }
trigger_event: { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }
```

therefore, in any case you'll need to have two triggers, and, if you don't want to repeat some code in them, you have to use stored procedure. Since you don't want to use stored procedure, I believe there's no acceptable solution for your problem.

Comment: man i hate this. what kind of old school technique is this -_- where is the problem by defining a trigger for 2 events. i thought that i need to use a procedure. 2 Triggers that both calls the same function, my professors would kill me if i would do this in a programm ......

Answer (score 0):

A trigger is associated with a table, and a particular event (insert, update, delete).
You have two actions: AFTER INSERT and AFTER DELETE, so you need two triggers.